# How to make a global object inside a method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, oop

I want to make an object inside a method, but it should also be available everywhere inside the program.

```
class abc():
   def random():
      print("abc")

def def():
   ob = abc()

def xyz():
   ob.random()
```

Is this possible?

Comment: *Objects* are neither global nor local. *Variables* are.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that's possible, but you need to define the variable at global scope and then use the global variable with `global` keyword when you are assigning/modifying the value inside a function/method.

```py
ob = None
class abc():
   def random():
      print("abc")

def def():
   global ob
   ob = abc()

def xyz():
   ob.random()
```

Another way (not recommended) is to create the variable from the function/method itself using `globals` buitin:

```py
class abc():
   def random():
      print("abc")

def def():
   globals()['ob'] = abc()

def xyz():
   ob.random()
```